# Writing a Magento GeoIP store redirect, problems with sharing links

Tags: php, magento, redirect, geoip

I currently have a Magento project where the customer wants a fairly simple GeoIP solution, we tried a few modules but all were bulky, messy and caused bugs in other places.

I ended up doing it using the GeoIP php library and .dat files and just creating a statement in the index.php, redirecting other users to /us and /eu folders which had index.php files that loaded the relevant stores. Looks like this

```
/########### GEOIP ############//
$geoipPath = 'includes/geoip.inc';
include($geoipPath);

$gi = geoip_open("includes/GeoIP.dat",GEOIP_STANDARD);

$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$country_code = geoip_country_code_by_addr($gi, $ip);
$euArray = array('DE','FR','AT','BE','HR','CY','CZ','DK','EE','FI','GR','HU','IS','IE','IT','LU','MD','MC','NL','NO','PL','PT','RO','RU','SK','SI','ES','SE','CH','UA','VA');
if(strtoupper($country_code) == "US"){
    $mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : 'us_site';
    $mageRunType = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'website';

    Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);

}elseif(in_array(strtoupper($country_code),$euArray)){
    $mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : 'eu_site';
    $mageRunType = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'website';

    Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);

}else{
    $mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : '';
    $mageRunType = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'store';

    Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);
}
```

This works well except for when sending out newsletter and such where the link is too http://example.com/our-new-offers.html

When a US/EU customer clicks this link they just get redirected to the homepage, anyone know a way to get round this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've got the other stores set up on subdirectories, can't you just redirect to them to the other store and append the URI?

Taking your code above:

```
if(strtoupper($country_code) == "US"){
    header('Location: http://example.com/us' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);    
}
elseif(in_array(strtoupper($country_code),$euArray)){
    header('Location: http://example.com/eu' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
}else{
    $mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : '';
    $mageRunType = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'store';

    Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);
}
```